# Concurrent processes in C

Tags: c, fork

How can I have 3 processes running in parallel? Is this solution below correct?
In my solution I put some code to see the time elapsed and I think this is tunning in sequential mode. I need to put pid1, pid2 and pid3 running at the same time.

```
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
        //code...
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
} else if(pid > 0) {
        pid1 = fork();
        if(pid1 == 0) {
                //pid1 code...
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else if(pid1 > 0) {
            waitpid(pid1, &status, 0);
    } else {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    if(pid2 == 0) {
                //pid2 code...
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else if(pid2 > 0) {
        waitpid(pid2, &status, 0);
    } else {
        printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
    }

    pid3 = fork();
    if(pid3 == 0) {
                //pid3 code...
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else if(pid3 > 0) {
        waitpid(pid3, &status, 0);
    } else {
            printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
    }
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
```

Comment: One note: the number of concurrent processes you can create has nothing to do with the C language. It's controlled by your operating system, and on any modern operating system the number of concurrent processes supported is in the thousands.

Answer (score 4):

You keep waiting for one child to complete before you launch the next.  Try something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
        error

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        child does thing
        exit
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    wait(&status);
}
```

**EDIT**

So just change your code to something like this and wait at the end.

```
    if (pid2 == 0)
    {
        //pid2 code...
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
        if (pid2 < 0)
        {
            printf("Fork error %d.\n", errno);
        }

   //....same outline for 3, etc.
```

Comment: Huummm, ok. But in that solution I can't differ the child's, right? I mean, my 3 processes have to do different code... In your solution they will do the same, right?

Comment: Yes but you don't have to do it in a loop.  You can have three separate forks with the child executing different code in each but don't wait on each to finish before continuing in the parent if you want it to run in parallel.  If distinguishing between the child pids is important put them in an array or list and wait on them after you created all the children.

Comment: Now I stay with processes in the shell (running, I think). Because with the wait() it only waits for on of the processes, right? The other's keep there...

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking.  There is no shell involved here.  The children will finish on their own.  The OS will store the children's info until you collect them with wait().  You can collect them all in a loop as they finish, one after the other.  All wait() does (normally) is block until a child is finished so the parent can examine its return status info.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [wrap](http://homepage.mac.com/pauljlucas/software/wrap-2.9.tar.gz) program, specifically the code for `wrapc`.  It forks itself twice, execs one child into `wrap`, reads, writes to `wrap`, then reads back in the other child.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague -- are you seeing 3 processes running in parallel or not?
the way your code is written you are exiting the child processes straight away.